# How might "one mind" in Philippians 2:2 compare with "your mind" in Mark 12:30?

Tags: word-study, mark, philippians

> "complete my joy by being of the same mind, having the same love, being in full accord and of one mind." Philippians 2:2 ESV -**One mind**. mind/phroneo.

> "And you shall love the Lord your God with all your mind and with all your strength." Mark 12:30 ESV-**Your mind**. mind/dianoia.

Are these phrases describing Christian thinking from different points of view?

If so, which points of view?

How do they compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark is outlining a teaching under Law. Teaching Torah. Paul is teaching from a perspective of Grace. ‘Rebirth’ comes with a ‘new heart’. Under ‘law’ *you* are to love, with all of *your* body, soul, mind. Under ‘grace’ you have to let that [new] ‘love’ *in you* ‘work’ it’s way out. And, that ‘love’ will be the same ‘love’ that’s shed abroad in every believers ‘heart’, so *that* should lead to, or at the least, be a ‘foundation’ for unity - that is, ‘one mind’.

So your answer is yes.

1 COR 1: 10 I appeal to you, brothers and sisters, in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that all of you agree with one another in what you say and that there be no divisions among you, but that you be perfectly united in mind and thought.

But, to *specifically* answer your question - “*Are these phrases describing Christian thinking from different points of view?*” - In Philippians 2:2 Paul was speaking of *unity* - ‘one mind’. Where as in  Mark 12:30 Jesus is *not* talking about ‘unity’, but rather ‘[just] ***you***. *Your* mind.

So your answer is ‘yes’.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus quoted from the Shema in Mark 12:30, and it doesn't have φρονέω in it.

> 30 καὶ ἀγαπήσεις κύριον τὸν θεόν σου ἐξ ὅλης °τῆς καρδίας σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης °1τῆς ψυχῆς σου ⸋καὶ ἐξ ὅλης °1τῆς διανοίας σου⸌ καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τῆς ἰσχύος σου⸆.
> (Mark 12:30, NA28)

The closest word in Mark 12:30 is διάνοια.

> διάνοια, ας, ἡ ... LXX, here nearly always for לֵב, לֵבָב).
>
> 1. understanding, intelligence, mind as the organ of νοεῖν ...
> 2. mind as a kind of thinking, disposition, thought ...
> 3. purpose, plan ...
> 4. in an unfavorable sense imagination, conceit ... Pl. senses, impulses in a bad sense ...

> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 187). University of Chicago Press.

A similar word Mark 12:30 has is καρδίa.  As with its Hebrew counterpart, it refers to the whole inner person.

> It is often possible to render καρδίa by a number of different terms depending upon the immediate context, for example, ‘mind,’ ‘intention,’ ‘purpose,’ or ‘desire.’
> --
> Louw, J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). In Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 320). United Bible Societies.

Apparently, both these words in Mark 12:30 translated לֵבָב in the Shema.

> לֵבָב S3824 TWOT1071a GK4222251 n.m. ψ 104:15 inner man, mind, will, heart;
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 523). Clarendon Press.

Phil. 2:2 does have φρονέω.

> πληρώσατέ μου τὴν χαρὰν ἵνα τὸ αὐτὸ φρονῆτε, τὴν αὐτὴν ἀγάπην ἔχοντες, σύμψυχοι, τὸ ⸀ἓν φρονοῦντες,*
> (Phil. 2:2, MA28)

τὸ αὐτὸ φρονῆτε means to have the same attitude. Paul defined this attitude in Phil. 2:3-11.  If everyone has the attitude that Paul defined, then they have the same attitude.

> φρονέω: (derivative of the base φρον‘thoughtful planning,’ 26.15) to employ one’s faculty for thoughtful planning, with emphasis upon the underlying disposition or attitude—‘to have an attitude, to think in a particular manner.’
> --
> Louw, J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). In Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 324). United Bible Societies.

This passage shows a connection between the above two:

> We love because he first loved us. 20 If anyone says, “I love God,” and hates his brother, he is a liar; for he who does not love his brother whom he has seen cannot love God whom he has not seen. 21 And this commandment we have from him: whoever loves God must also love his brother.
> (1 John 4:19–21, ESV)

Comment: "one" mind-we have the mind of Christ?

Comment: @Stroud Correct

Answer (score 1):

**How might "one mind" in Philippians 2:2 compare with "your mind" in Mark 12:30?**

> "complete my joy by being of the same mind, having the same love,
> being in full accord and of one mind." Philippians 2:2 ESV -One mind.
> mind/*phroneo*.
>
> "And you shall love the Lord your God with all your mind and with all
> your strength." Mark 12:30 ESV-Your mind. mind/**dianoia.**

**Mark 12:30 " All  Your Mind" or full mental faculties.**

This means that we use our full mental faculties to understand God's personality, the purpose for humankind, and other requirements. We express our love for God by mentally submitting our whole mind and doing things his way and also helping others to understand and love Him. As in:

John 17:3 NASB

> 3 And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God,
> and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.

Acts 17:11 NASB

> 11 Now these people were more noble-minded than those in Thessalonica,
> [a]for they received the word with great eagerness, examining the
> Scriptures daily to see whether these things were so.

1 Peter 1:13 NASB

> 13 Therefore, prepare your minds for action, keep sober in spirit, set
> your hope completely on the grace to be brought to you at the
> revelation of Jesus Christ.

**Philippians 2:2  "One Mind," means to strive for unity**.

Paul urges  the Philippian Christians to strive for unity, being of the same thought, as in:

1 Peter 3:8 NASB

> 8 To sum up, all of you be harmonious, sympathetic, loving,
> compassionate, and humble;

1 Corinthians 1:10 NASB

> 10 Now I urge you, brothers and sisters, by the name of our Lord Jesus
> Christ, that you all agree and that there be no divisions among you,
> but that you be made complete in the same mind and in the same
> judgment.

2 Corinthians 13:11  NASB

> 11 Finally, brothers and sisters, rejoice, mend your ways, be
> comforted, be like-minded, live in peace; and the God of love and
> peace will be with you.

Comment: Ozzie Is John 17:3 knowing, intellectual knowing about,or spiritual knowledge as in that which causes us to say "Abba Father"?

Comment: C Stroud It is spiritual knowledge, the Greek text implies making an ongoing effort to get better acquainted,it refers to a deepening personal relationship with God brought about by ever-increasing knowledge of God and Christ and a growing trust in them.   Mere knowledge or intellectual power is not enough to bring one into God’s favor.Luke 10:21 NASB  “I praise You, Father, Lord of heaven and earth, that You have hidden these things from the wise and intelligent and have revealed them to infants. Yes, Father, for doing so was well-pleasing in Your sight." [ Read 1 Cor 1:19 and 2 Cor 2:6]

Answer (score 1):

Note that in classical Greek (from which Koine Greek arose) had a lot to say about the concept of "mind" and thus had many words to describe the various aspects of mind, thinking, and expression of thought.

In the NT, there are no less that six words that are translated "mind"

1. νοῦς (nous) = mind, understanding, reason, eg, Luke 24:45, Rom 1:28, etc.
2. διάνοια (dionia) = the mind, disposition, thought, eg, Matt 22:37, Mark 12:30, Luke 1:51, 10:27, Eph 2:3, 4:18, Col 1:21, Heb 10:8, etc.
3. ἔννοια (ennonia) = thinking, thoughtfulness, moral understanding, eg, Heb 4:12, 1 Peter 4:1.
4. νόημα (noéma) = thought, purpose, eg, 2 Cor 2:11, 3:14, 4:4, 10:5, etc.
5. γνώμη (gnómé) = purpose, opinion, consent, decision, eg, Acts 20:3, 1 Cor 1;10, 7:25, 40, 2 Cor 8:10, etc.
6. φρόνημα (phronéma) = the thought (that which is in the mind), eg, Rom 8:6, 7, 27.

This list could be extended to include some other words which are also occasionally (and legitimately) translated "mind" in some places by some versions such as:

7. φρόνησις (phronésis) = understanding, practical wisdom, eg, Luke 1:17, Eph 1:8.
8. ψυχή (psuché) = soul but translated "mind by the AV in Acts 14:2, Phil 1:27, Heb 12:3
9. λόγος (logos) = word or expression of the mind, which, while not translated "mind", is so closely associated with the same concept I list it here for completeness

The meanings for all of these overlap somewhat and only include the nouns.  If we include the verbs, the list grows much longer.

I have included the very helpful entry from W E Vine, "Expository Dictionary of NT Words" in the appendix below.

In the case of the specific words in the OP,

- Mark 12:30 is a noun, διάνοια (dianoia).  BDAG gives this meaning for this verse: **the facility of thinking, comprehending and reasoning, *understanding, intelligence, mind***, eg, Eph 4;18, 1 John 5:20, Heb 8:10, 10:16, Matt 22:37, Mark 12:30, Luke 10:27.
- Phil 2:2, is a verb, φρονέω (phroneó). Note that this word occurs 26 times in the NT, 10 of them in Philippians alone and nine times in the second half of Romans.  BDAG gives this meaning for this verse: **to have an opinion with regard to something, *think, form/hold opinion, judge***, eg, Acts 28:22, Phil 1:7, 3:15a, 15b, 4:10a, Gal 5:10, 2 Cor 13:11, Phil 2:2a, b, 3:16, 4:2, etc.

Note that φρονέω (phroneó) occurs three times in this passage, Phil 2:2 (twice) and V5.  Further, BDAG lists a slightly different meaning in V5 from that in V2.  However, that is beyond the scope of this question.

Note that, again, these meanings overlap slightly.  However, both words describe the functioning of the transformed "mind" (Rom 12:2), ie, the Christian mind (as distinct from the unconverted mind).  That is, the sanctified mind has its thoughts focused on spiritual realities and transformed to be like that of Christ (1 Cor 2:16, 2 Cor 3:18).

**APPENDIX - W E Vine, "mind" (nouns)**

**A — 1: νοῦς**
(Strong's #3563 — Noun Masculine — nous — nooce )
"mind," denotes, speaking generally, the seat of reflective consciousness, comprising the faculties of perception and understanding, and those of feeling, judging and determining. Its use in the NT may be analyzed as follows: it denotes

(a) the faculty of knowing, the seat of the understanding, Luke 24:45; Romans 1:28; 14:5; 1 Corinthians 14:15,19; Ephesians 4:17; Philippians 4:7; Colossians 2:18; 1 Timothy 6:5; 2 Timothy 3:8; Titus 1:15; Revelation 13:18; 17:9;

(b) counsels, purpose, Romans 11:34 (of the "mind" of God); 12:2; 1 Corinthians 1:10; 2:16 , twice (1) of the thoughts and counsels of God, (2) of Christ, a testimony to His Godhood; Ephesians 4:23;

(c) the new nature, which belongs to the believer by reason of the new birth, Romans 7:23,25 , where it is contrasted with "the flesh," the principle of evil which dominates fallen man. Under (b) may come 2 Thessalonians 2:2 , where it stands for the determination to be steadfast amidst afflictions, through the confident expectation of the day of rest and recompense mentioned in the first chapter.

**2: διάνοια**
(Strong's #1271 — Noun Feminine — dianoia — dee-an'-oy-ah )
lit. "a thinking through, or over, a meditation, reflecting," signifies

(a) like No. 1, "the faculty of knowing, understanding, or moral reflection," (1) with an evil significance, a consciousness characterized by a perverted moral impulse, Ephesians 2:3 (plural); 4:18; (2) with a good significance, the faculty renewed by the Holy Spirit, Matthew 22:37; Mark 12:30; Luke 10:27; Hebrews 8:10; 10:16; 1 Peter 1:13; 1 John 5:20;

(b) "sentiment, disposition" (not as a function but as a product); (1) in an evil sense, Luke 1:51 , "imagination;" Colossians 1;21; (2) in a good sense, 2 Peter 3:1 .

**3: ἔννοια**
(Strong's #1771 — Noun Feminine — ennoia — en'-noy-ah )
"an idea, notion, intent," is rendered "mind" in 1 Peter 4:1; see INTENT.

**4: νόημα**
(Strong's #3540 — Noun Neuter — noema — no'-ay-mah )
"thought, design," is rendered "minds" in 2 Corinthians 3:14; 4:4; 11:3; Philippians 4:7; see DEVICE , No. 2.

**5: γνώμη**
(Strong's #1106 — — gnome — gno'-may )
"a purpose, judgment, opinion," is translated "mind" in Philemon 1:14; Revelation 17:13 . See JUDGMENT , No. 4.

**6: φρόνημα**
(Strong's #5427 — Noun Neuter — phronema — fron'-ay-mah )
denotes "what one has in the mind, the thought" (the content of the process expressed in phroneo, "to have in mind, to think"); or "an object of thought;" in Romans 8:6 (AV, "to be carnally minded" and "to be spiritually minded"), the RV, adhering to the use of the noun, renders by "the mind of the flesh," in vv. 6,7, and "the mind of the spirit," in v. 6. In Romans 8:27 the word is used of the "mind" of the Holy Spirit.